# nvcc: Updating cuda nvcc on windows

Tags: nvcc

I would like to update the `nvcc cuda compiler driver` on windows.
What is the easiest way to do so using the command line or the Anaconda prompt?

Current version:

```py
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:36:24_Pacific_Standard_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
```

Comment: Did u find the answer?

Comment: yes, did you find the way to update it?